# Can I read ERC-20 token address from token Symbol?

Tags: erc-20, python, web3j

I am able to read token's details directly from the token address using web3py library, however, I want to achieve the vice-versa where I can read the token's address just from the token symbol using any API.
Is this achievable?

My current code is as follows:

```
import json
from web3 import Web3

# Fill in your infura API key here
infura_url = "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/API_KEY"

web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(infura_url))

# Get it from Etherscan and change true => True and false => False
abi = [{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address[]","name":"addresses","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"balances","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":False,"inputs":[{"indexed":True,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":True,"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":False,"internalType":"uint256","name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":False,"inputs":[{"indexed":True,"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":True,"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":False,"internalType":"uint256","name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint8","name":"","type":"uint8"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"subtractedValue","type":"uint256"}],"name":"decreaseAllowance","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"addedValue","type":"uint256"}],"name":"increaseAllowance","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}]

address = '0x990f341946A3fdB507aE7e52d17851B87168017c'

contract = web3.eth.contract(address=address, abi=abi)

# Let's print Name of Token
print(contract.functions.name().call())
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this is easily possible since multiple tokens can have the same symbol. This would require searching tokens by symbol, and deducing which contract is the one you're looking for. [Etherscan's API](https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/tokens) for example *does not* allow for the searching of tokens by symbol.

Comment: As Ryan mentioned, the Etherscan API is your best option. And if you want to code something and run it locally, you can download a list of tokens in JSON [from this repo](https://github.com/viaprotocol/tokenlists/tree/main/tokenlists) and search by the symbol.